# Simple problem on Unity 2D with empty object collider

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to make one empty object that player can pass but enemy can't pass.
I have added collider to the object. so I can see triggering of collider event with object and player, enemy.
But both are passing the object. Only I need player passing.
What I should add?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the Unity Physics 2D settings (Edit>project settings) and then scroll down and uncheck the unwanted colliders that u don’t want to collide with each other.

Make sure to give the player, the object collider and the enemy a unique layer.

Uncheck the layer between the player and the object collider layer hence will allow the player only to pass.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options.

One of them is using [Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and the [Physics2D -> Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html). Here you can define which layers shall be interacting with each other and which should ignore each other.

See also [Layer-based Collision](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html).

So e.g. have three layers

- Player
- Enemy
- Goal

and make the collision matrix to allow collision between `Enemy` and `Goal` but ignore collision between `Player` and `Goal`. Then make all colliders `isTrigger = false`.

=> Only the object(s) with the layer `Player` can pass the object(s) on the layer `Goal` while the object(s) with layer `Enemy` will collide with them, thus can not pass them.

This can only be set up beforehand. You can however still make objects dynamically switch layers and thereby even on runtime control which objects can collide with each others.

---

As alternative you can also make collisions between specific individual colliders be ignored by using [`Physics2D.IgnoreCollision`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.IgnoreCollision.html)

> Makes the collision detection system ignore all collisions/triggers between collider1 and collider2.

Using this you can dynamically enable and disable collisions between specific colliders.

---

**But** if you actually want to be able to have an event be triggered by both player and enemy but the enemy shall not be able to pass the goal then your setup should probably be like

- Goal `isTrigger = false`
- Enemy `isTrigger = false`
- Player `isTrigger = true`

this way the player will pass the goal, the enemy won't.

Then you would use both `OnTriggerEnter2D` to detect the player collision and `OnCollisionEnter2D` to detect the enemy collision.

Comment: Seemed to be good. but if I set Enemy's isTrigger = false,
The Enemy object will not interact with the wall.